# Do we need two meta tags for the following or can we condense it down to one?

Tags: html

Why do we need two meta tags for the following,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Why can't we add charset="UTF-8" to the first meta tag itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need two meta tags because it's not valid to have both `charset` and `name` or `content` on a single `meta` tag.